# Books and articles on model theory for set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, model-theory, book-recommendation

I'm interested in books and/or articles which explore a little more in depth the model theory of set theory. I'm aware that most books on set theory have a section or two on models (e.g. Jech, Kunen), but these sections are generally redacted with a certain instrumental aim in mind. I'm more interested in books or articles that tackle the model theory for set theory head on; for instance, there seems to be a distinction between models and interpretations of set theory, yet most books don't examine that. In the same vein, it seems (correct me if I'm wrong) that, assuming ZFC is consistent, we can, as per the completeness theorem, also assume that it has a model. Yet we can't assume that this model is a standard transitive model, for then the theory would prove an inconsistency. If true, it'd be nice to see this fleshed out in a bit more detail.

Comment: When you say "models of set theory" it's often the meaning "class models", and those are beyond the reach of model theory in some sense. Transitive models are also beyond the reach of model theory, since model theoretic tools rarely guarantee that starting from a transitive model you will end up with a transitive model.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Do you have any good reference for this type of discussion? That's exactly the type of thing I'd like to read more about.

Comment: No, sorry. I can't think of anything good. Jech covers this, and probably any other advance set theory book. But the actual knowledge is eclectic, and you have to build it from learning a lot of things (e.g. Mostowski absoluteness theorem tells us that arithmetic statements are absolute between transitive models, sets of classes, so things like $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF)$ are true in the universe when there is a transitive model, so they must be true in the transitive model as well, therefore transitive models have a stronger consistency strength than just models.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila - That's a shame. Do you think Shepherdson's articles on inner models make for a good read about this?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm not that familiar with them. Again, this is really just the sort of knowledge you gain when you study set theory. The sort of stuff that builds itself up, and you suddenly realize that you understand things that you didn't try to learn in particular.