# References for Introductory Model Theory focusing on applications other than algebra

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, model-theory

I would appreciate suggestions for references (books, lecture notes, articles etc...) on Model Theory (at an introductory level) that don't focus mostly on algebra when giving examples and/or applying the theory.

It would be wonderful if there was also a nice reference that focuses on applications of model theory to set theory. It´s also fine if the references are aimed at someone already knowing the basics of Model Theory (but not something much more advanced than that).

Comment: Chang and Keisler's Model Theory (a classic in the field) doesn't rely on algebraic examples. I think they might do most of their work in the abstract (if that is something you are interested in). They incorporate a lot of set theory, but I'm not sure if they prove theorems about set theory using model theory. Hodges's Model Theory (The big one, not 'A Shorter Model Theory') is just scattered examples from everywhere. However, I also don't think this text emphasizes set theory as it emphasizes 'constructions of models'

Comment: There is very little model theory that is applied to models of set theory. I believe that Jesus wrote at least one answer on this issue before.

Comment: Okay, I can't find such answer; but I did find [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002006/books-and-articles-on-model-theory-for-set-theory) and a comment there which is probably what I had in mind.

Comment: The model theory of structures that have hight coding power has a very different flavour than the model theory of tame structures. For a taste, take a look to Kossak and Schmerl's book on models of arithmetic.